# Python IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python

Can anyone point me to what's wrong?

I got stuck on `newGrid.setValue(n[k][0], n[k][1], List[k])` trying to feed the values of each x/y of each coord into a different function, which takes three arguments, x y and value. Value is what is printed in a position on a grid, x & y are the coordinates.

> ```
> self.listOfRows[x - 1][y - 1] = value
> ```
>
> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

```
def gridMileage(List):
    x = []
    y = []
    n = []
    k = 0
    best = 0
    while len(List) > 0:
        for i in range(len(List)):
            x = List[i][0]
            y = List[i][1]
            n.append([x,y])
        if x > best:
            best = x
        elif y > best:
            best = y
        newGrid = Grid(best)
        while k < 2:
            newGrid.setValue(n[k][0], n[k][1], List[k])
            k = k + 1
        del List[0]
        del List[1]
        del n[0]
        del n[1]
        newGrid.setValue(n[0], n[0] + 1, math.sqrt((n[0][0] - n[1][0])**2 + (n[0][1] - n[1][1])**2))
        newGrid.setValue(n[1] + 1, n[1], math.sqrt((n[1][0] - n[0][0])**2 + (n[1][1] - n[0][1])**2))
        z = len(newGrid.listOfRows)
        while z > 0:
            print(newGrid.listOfRows[z - 1])
            z = z - 1

class Grid:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.listOfRows = []
        for i in range(n):
            row = []
            for j in range(n):
                row.append('*')
            self.listOfRows.append(row)

    def setValue (self, x, y, value):
        self.listOfRows[x - 1][y - 1] = value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that ultimately, you appear to be feeding in a list index that is either too small, or too large.

According to the error message, the problematic piece of code is `self.listOfRows[x - 1][y - 1] = value`. You call it by doing `newGrid.setValue(n[k][0], n[k][1], List[k])`. The problem can't be `List[k]`, since that's not what's causing the stacktrace.

**Therefore, that means either `n[k][0]` or `n[k][1]` is too big for `newGrid.listOfRows`.**

I would double-check your code by adding in print statements before that line to examine those two values, as well as double-checking exactly how large your grid is.

Since the only place you appear to add any values to `n` is at (I think?):

```
for i in range(len(List)):
    x = List[i][0]
    y = List[i][1]
    n.append([x,y])
```

...that implies that the root issue is ultimately with the `List` variable that you've passed in.

Comment: Thanks - I found that the error was with when I was determining the size of the grid, I'd used an If-Elif, and the grid had initialized itself to 1*1 - it hadn't checked if the y coord was bigger, so a coord (2, 3) couldn't be passed to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.listOfRows[x - 1][y - 1] = value
```

what if `x` and `y` are `0`
that gives you

```
self.listOfRows[-1][-1] = value
```

it doesnt exist

Comment: `self.listOfRows[x][y] = value`
`IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: List[i][0]
 newGrid.setValue(n[k][0], n[k][1], List[k])
you are sending an array into a value?